# how to catch errors inside components in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, components, try-catch, react-props

What's the standard for handling unexpected errors that may occur into the specific react components which may move away on page refresh, because of irrelevant data in props or state. As it will be good if we code our components in a specific manner to handle it by its own method.

Comment: Check this official documentation about error boundaries: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries

Comment: but what about the version less than 16 @aliankarali

Comment: You can use traditional try catch statements but the usage may depend on the specific case. You should give an example about your case.